# "could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to" in very simple example

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The following code throws the error:

> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'

```
interface Test {
    a: <T>() => { b: T }
}

const eg: Test = { 
    a: () => ({ b: 3})
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHJwBcyAPKgHwAUAlMgLxW7IBGZqyAvnr3ggD2ILMggBzTpmyNWBIqWT0mLGjnZkAzNzp88QA)

Why does it throw this error, and how can I make it accept that the type it is getting is the only type it will get?

---

Exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
type ForeignKeyValueType = {
    foreignKey: <SCHEMA extends object>() => {
        schema: SCHEMA,
        propName: SCHEMA extends { props: any } ? KeyOf<SCHEMA["props"]> : never
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235595/discussion-between-seph-reed-and-jcalz).

Comment: If you insist on `Test` not having a generic parameter, then what you are asking for is an *existential type* of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)... and `Test`'s `a` method would be of the type `<exists T>() => { b: T }`... but TypeScript does not support existential quantification directly (and few languages do).  There are ways to represent them indirectly [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mx58XW), but most people get along all right without doing this.  I'm not sure if "readonly generics" is the same as existential types.

Comment: When you say you want `<T extends object>() => ({ obj: T; key: keyof T; })` what you might really want is `<exists T extends object>{obj: T, key: keyof T}` which can be indirectly represented like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0Lnom), but I'm still not sure how important that use case is for you.  If I hand you a pair of `obj` and `key` like that, the only thing you can do is `obj[key]`, right?  But `obj[key]` is going to be of type `T[keyof T]` which is effectively `unknown` to you and all you can do is stuff like `String(obj[key])` or some other operation that takes `unknown` or `any` values.

Comment: Oh I see from [microsoft/TypeScript#45311](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45311) that by "readonly generics" you mean class-body scoped type aliases.  But that wouldn't give you a solution to this problem as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

You must move the generics function type parameters to the parameter of whole interface. In this way, we can makes the type parameter visible to all the other members of the interface.

```
interface Test<T> {
    a: () => { b: T }
}

const eg: Test<number> = { 
    a: () => ({ b: 3})
}
```

Comment: Dang.  This won't work for me.  My interface does not need to know anything about the generics, and I can't pass this buck onto my users.